# An equation with Gamma Euler function in critical strip

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

Let
$$
D=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0<\Re(z)<\frac{1}{2} \text{ or } \frac{1}{2}<\Re(z)<1 \}
$$
that is the critical strip without critical line.

I have to find if the following equation, with Gamma Euler function, has any root in $D$
$$
\Gamma(z)
=
\dfrac
{\pi^z}
{\cos
\left(
\dfrac{\pi}{2} \cdot z
\right)
\cdot
2^{1-z}
}
\cdot
\dfrac
{1-2^{1-z}}
{1-2^z}
$$
I have already posted this question on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324618/an-equation-with-gamma-euler-function-in-critical-strip but they gave to me an "Imprecise answer"

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: In MO's answer $f(1-z) = -f(z)$ only means $F(z) = f(1/2+z)$ is odd. I don't see what it meant with Hermite theorem. Since also $F(\bar{z}) = \overline{F(z)}$ it means $F$ is purely imaginary on $\Re(z) = 0$. Then you can find an asymptotic for $F(it)$ and $\Im( F(z))$ in order to use the argument principle.

Comment: @reuns infact, the answer in MO is a non answer. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: So can you use the Stirling approximation to make clear the asymptotic of the $\log $ of the LHS and RHS in the critical strip (and specify you want to know the solutions of $\eta(s) = \eta(1-s) \ne 0$)

Comment: @reuns you are a magician because i really want to know if $\eta(s) = \eta(1-s) \neq 0$ has solution. I posted the questione like that because I thought that it was more simple. so has  that equation solution with $\eta$ function. thanks so much